# Scanf produces segmentation fault for non-pointer argument

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program in c that outputs the html file, actually I am learning CGI programming. This program stops at run time when it executes the loop ('for' and 'while' both).

The error returned is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

The code(only the segment of program that is causing the problem) is:

```
void main()
{
int track=0;
int question_no;
printf("\nHow many questions?\t");
scanf("%d",question_no);
while(track<=question_no)
    {
        printf("\nAshish");
        track++;
    }
}
```

Actually I get the answer: I should use '&' when inputting value into `question_no`.

But my next question is **WHY?** should I use `&`? Because I defined `question_no` as `int` only not int pointer.

Comment: Segmentation fault = When you are trying to access something you shouldn't

Comment: *"Because I defined question_no as int only not int pointer."* - That would be why.  `scanf` needs a pointer in order to mutate the value.  It expects a pointer, you pass it an int which is converted to a pointer which has some garbage value (address).

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Adjusted the title since you don't seem to be asking what a segmentation fault is.

Comment: @dreamlax I am not returning any value at all. I've used void. Even gcc is not showing any warning.

Comment: @AshishTomer "immutation" is not a word I have ever encountered. `void main` is illegal, and GCC 4.9 complains "error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’". Note that there is an implicit `return 0;` which applies only to `main`, so you don't need to add a `return` to write a correct program.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Oh! Actually you people here are pros. Actually I was asking about "mutate",that google tells means changing forms, I am not English speaking :P, so what does it mean in programming?
-------------------------------------------------
Does your last line mean that "return 0" is a compulsory part of a program, in main()?
-------------------------------------------------
I am a beginner actually, I hope you will help me. :)

Comment: @AshishTomer I mean the opposite; you do *not* need to write `return 0;`. "Mutate" means to change an object, i.e. its value.

Comment: okay :) you were very helpful :)

Comment: Some of us are pros and some are not. StackOverflow helped me start on the way to a very high level of C++ expertise, but there are no requirements for contributing here besides the willingness to do so :)

Comment: @AshishTomer: You do not need to write a `return` statement in `main` but it ***must*** return `int` or else your program is considered ill-formed. Even if you are not returning a value. `main` is a function that is treated specially so that you don't need to have a `return` statement.

Comment: Hmmm! Now this concept is clear to me. It's best place to learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why should I use &? Because I defined question_no as int only not int pointer

That would be why. scanf needs a pointer in order to mutate the value. It expects a pointer, you pass it an int which is converted to a pointer which has some garbage value (address).

Comment: Yes thank you :) you have already explained it to me though :) It was very helpful. I would be delighted if you could explain me what this "mutate" thing is.

Comment: @AshishTomer In this context, "mutate" simply means "change". A function in C cannot change its caller's local variables, unless it's given pointers to them.

Comment: Yes, call by reference. :)

Comment: @AshishTomer: There is no such thing as "pass by reference" in C

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
scanf("%d",question_no);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&question_no);
```

and see what happens...

`scanf` takes a pointer to the memory location where to put the int value. So it tried to use `question_no` as an address and that caused the seg fault. `question_no` at that point had never been initialized so it could have been anything and the program tried to write to that location.

The `&` returns the address of `question_no`.

Comment: I get it. But my question is **why should I use '&'?**

Comment: @AshishTomer And the answer is that the `&` operator produces an address.

Comment: I think your answer is my paragraph and last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Basically a segmentation faut is when your program attempts to access memory that it has not been assigned. You particular issue is this line, which invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you are using `question_no` uninitialized here:

```
scanf("%d",question_no);
```

and you are treating `question_no` as if it was a *pointer*, this is what you want:

```
scanf("%d",&question_no);
```

Enabling warnings would probably have helped you spot this error, `gcc` provides the following warning:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

For `gcc` I often use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and you can find a complete [description here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). Some documents for [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Shafik yaghmour. It was very helpful. Can you tell me how do I enable warnings through gcc.

Comment: @AshishTomer there are a lot of different flags but I often use these `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @AshishTomer I added a link to the gcc docs on their warning flags as well.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` is a C function, and since C doesn't have 'references' like C++ has, passing a pointer to `scanf` is the only way `scanf` is able to store its results. If `scanf` doesn't have a pointer telling it where to store the result, then there is no way it can give its result back to the caller.

Thus `scanf` is written to accept (and expect) pointers as its arguments, and if you give it `int's` instead of pointers it will simply attempt to use those `int's` as pointers - which will likely cause a seg-fault.

Answer (score 1):

'scanf()' stores values, so it needs a place to store them.This is done by providing the addresses of where to store the values.'&' is used to refer addresses of variable in scanf statement.